# how to convert the jsp script to slightly. Also where can i get the slightly full documentation for the available tags usage

Tags: aem

How to convert the `<%  String rootpath =currentPage.getAbsoluteParent(3).getPath(); %>` code into the SLIGHTLY tag for printing the rootpath value.

Example i can get the currentpage children by using `<ul data-sly-list.first="${currentPage.listChildren}">
  <li>${child.title}</li>
</ul>`

***Also where can i get the slightly full documentation for the available tags usage*** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it is not possible.

Sightly is more of a templating language and all your business logic should be achieved either through a Java or Javascript `Use API`.

To achieve this, you can either use a JS Use API (a simplest example shown below,a file named helper.js residing in the same directory as my sightly HTML).

```
use(function () {
    return {
        rootPath: currentPage.getAbsoluteParent(2).getPath()
    };
});
```

And then you can use this in your sightly file as shown below.

```
<div data-sly-use.helper="helper.js">
    ${helper.rootPath}
</div>
```

And additionally, your example list wouldn't run because you have created an object `first` whereas you are referring to `child` within the list. It should be

```
<ul data-sly-list.child="${currentPage.listChildren}">
  <li>${child.title}</li>
</ul>
```

The full documentation of Sightly can be found [here](http://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly.html). You can get the introduction to Sightly through this [experience delivers blogs](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/sightly-intro-part-1/). The entire Sightly specification can be found [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md).